# Rails/Rspec specific test case under 'development' environment for workaround

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I normally run RSpec with `test` environment with CircleCI.

Is there any way to run specific test case under `development` environment for workaround.

P.S. I found some issue on rails-spec which acting up under test environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `allow(Rails).to receive(:env).and_return(ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new("development"))`